# How to Export table data based on condition using NatTable Export API?

Tags: eclipse, export, nattable

Currently My export is working properly, As i registered the export command handler like this

```
 compositeLayer.registerCommandHandler(new ExportCommandHandler(compositeLayer));

 natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultExportBinding());
```

From My Export Button I am calling this command

```
   @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        natTable.doCommand(
                new ExportCommand(
                        natTable.getConfigRegistry(),
                        natTable.getShell()));
    }
```

But I want to export only selected rows if the rows are selected or else all the data should be exported.
As I registered with composite Layer, it is exporting all the data s..

User wants an option to export either selected row or all the visible rows, based on that, we need to export the row data.
How to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported out of the box. You need to implement a custom `ITableExporter` and register it for `ExportConfigAttributes#TABLE_EXPORTER`.

Have a look at the `NatExporter` to get a better idea.